# Connection could not be established when sending swiftmailer email through symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, google-apps, symfony-2.3, swiftmailer

Every time I try to send an email through a google apps account with swiftmailer in symfony 2.3.11, I get the following message

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com
>   [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in
>   name resolution #0] 500 Internal Server Error -
>   Swift_TransportException

I googled it but I didn't get any results so I must be doing something wrong.

config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuraftion swiftmailer:
    transport:  gmail
    username:   info@*******.com
    password:   **
```

Controller that sends email :

```
/* send an email to user */
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Thank you')
    ->setFrom('info@********.com')
    ->setTo($email)
    ->setBody(
    $this->renderView(
        'xyProfileBundle:Mailer:thankyou.html.twig', 
        array('email' => $email, 'token' => $token)
        )
    )
    ->setContentType("text/html");
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your configuration of swiftmailer is not complete. Please complete it. Are you in development environment? Using gmail as transport use specific ports, be sure they're not closed :-) .

Comment: Symfony cookbook says that you only define "gmail" and not host and ports. They are being given automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your host is not able to resolve smtp.gmail.com.

Try to ping it:

```
ping smtp.gmail.com
```

And:

```
 php -r 'var_dump(gethostbyname("smtp.gmail.com"));'
```

Comment: thanks, Naji - at least I found the source of the problem. Apache runs from inside an ubuntu server vm which appears to have dns misconfigured.

Comment: how did you configure it @Radolino ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the IP address 74.125.206.109 instead of domain name (smtp.gmail.com)